# How to stop children from clipping when using dynamic height parents?

Tags: jquery, css

I made a panel box like this:

**HTML**

```
<section class="panel">
    <div class="title">Hot</div>

    <div class="content">
        <a href="">Article</a>
        <a href="">Article</a>
        <a href="">Article</a>
        <a href="">Article</a>
        <a href="">Article</a>
        <a href="">Article</a>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#body #rightPanel .panel {
    width: 220px;
    height: calc((100% - 160px) / 2);

    overflow: hidden;
}

#body #rightPanel .panel .content {
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    height: calc(100% - 34px);
}

#body #rightPanel .panel .content a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 27px;
    display: block;
}
```

The panel has a dynamic size according to the viewport size and works pretty much how I want it to. But if you look at the image below you will notice the obvious problem: the last element is clipped.

[image]

How can I only display a child element *only* if he can be displayed in full? A sort of all-or-nothing for children?

I would love a pure CSS solution but I don't mind using some JS/jQuery.

**EDIT**

Should anyone stumble here and look for the answer: Adam's answer works but ended up cropping one more element than needed. I slightly simplified his code into:

```
function resizePanelArticles() {
    var panelHeight = $(".content").height();
    $("a").show().each(function() {
        if ($(this).position().top > panelHeight) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this without javascript is changing `height: calc((100% - 160px) / 2);` to `min-height: calc((100% - 160px) / 2);`. This isn't exactly what you want as it will make enough room for the rest of them instead of cut them off, but it's the only css only way I could think of.

This can easily be done with javascript though. Basically we iterate through each `a` element and get the position of the bottom of the element with `$(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight()` and check it against the container. We also do it on the window loading and the window resizing, this is because it's a dynamic height so it will change, meaning if the window is resized it will have to be recalculated.

```
function resize(){
    var c = $('.panel .content').innerHeight();
    $('.panel .content a').show().each(function(){
        if($(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight() > c){
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}

$(window).on('load resize', resize);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5VLEa/1/)

Comment: For some reason when I iterate over each `a` element the way you do it, they each return exactly the same `position().top` (in my case all 6 elements at position top 636px)

Comment: @Juicy hm, can you try to set `.panel`'s css `position:relative`? see if that works if not I think I'd have to see it. Could you make a fiddle of it not working?

Comment: Position relative did the trick! I tweaked your code a bit to get the exact desired effect but overall it works!

Comment: Why did you user the innerHeight of the .content and added the outerHeight to the position().top when checking if > c? On my side it worked better by just getting the .content height() and not adding the outerHeight. (Your solution ended up cropping one more element than necessary)

Comment: @Juicy The way I wrote it is so it gets the `innerHeight` of the container which would be just the visible parts. Then test it against the `top` position of the element plus that elements `outerHeight` which would be the entire elements area. This means that if just 1 pixel of the element is outside the visible area it will not show it. I basically put it in a way of; if the **enitre** element isn't in the visual viewport then hide it.